# Auto Fill ModelForm with data already stored in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I got a form as shown below and I want it to be filled with information from the database when its HTML is rendered. I am passing the id of the Coworker as a parameter for the view.

See code below:

**view.py**

```
def EditCoworker(request, id):
    form = FormEditCoworker(Coworkers.objects.get(id=id))
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormEditCoworker(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirmation_message = "Coworker information updated successfully!"
            return render(request, "coworkers/coworkers.html", locals())
        else:
            return render(request, "coworkers/edit_coworker.html", locals())
    return render(request, 'coworkers/edit_coworker.html', locals())
```

**forms.py**

```
class FormEditCoworker(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Coworkers
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^edit_coworker/(?P<id>[\d]+)$', views.EditCoworker),
```

Of course the code in my views.py is not right.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
form = FormEditCoworker(Coworkers.objects.get(id=id))
```

Should be

```
form = FormEditCoworker(instance=Coworkers.objects.get(id=id))
```

Although you should really handle the case where the Coworker doesn't exist

```
form = FormEditCoworker(instance=get_object_or_404(Coworkers, id=id))
```

EDIT: As Alisdair said, you should also pass the instance keyword arg to the bound form also

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Coworkers, id=id)
form = FormEditCoworker(instance=instance)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = FormEditCoworker(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

Comment: The instance should be provided to the bound form as well.

Comment: It is working fine but now I got another problem. When I click on Save Changes, instead of updating the user information, it creates another instance for it. :(

Comment: Alasdair was correct, you need to pass the instance to the bound form. I have updated my answer

Comment: @LucasRezende, this is not working in django 2.2. instance is not a valid argument.